# Failed to create/update status 401 when deploying replicaset on ops manager

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, openshift

I have local mode ops manager and mongodb enterprise kubernetes operator on openshift environment. I set an api key in the ops manager and create a secret and config map. However when I am trying to deploy a replicaset I get an error message "failed to create/update status 401".